# Cisco ASA 5545 traffic shaping possibility?

Tags: cisco-asa, firewall

I am running a ASA 5545 and I would like to throttle some outgoing traffic without dropping it, when it is bursting over a certain speed limit.
Has anyone been able to do this on ASA5545 ?
I am aware that some ASA have restricted capabilities regarding traffic shaping... The problem is that I cannot really test before asking...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "_throttle some outgoing traffic without dropping it_?" You can only queue so much, then traffic will be dropped when the queue is full. Throttling traffic _will_ result in some traffic being dropped.

Comment: Hello Ron,
Thank you for your quick reply.
As you have previously commented out on Joe's comment, I am looking to shape the outgoing traffic without dropping anything when it is reaching a burst limit.

Comment: I haven't seen anything explicit regarding the buffering size for the traffic bursting over the configured limit.

Here is the kind of configuration that I would like to have :

ciscoasa(config-pmap)#policy-map qos_outside_policy
ciscoasa(config-pmap)# class class-default
ciscoasa(config-pmap-c)# shape average 2000000 
ciscoasa(config-pmap-c)#exit
ciscoasa(config-pmap)#exit
ciscoasa(config-pmap-c)# service-policy qos_outside_policy interface 
outside
Any idea if this is configurable on ASA 5545 ?

Comment: You really aren't going to be able to guarantee not dropping any traffic. The best you could do is to get a very large pipe and a big percentage of the bandwidth for your traffic class. If this is going outside your network, it's likely that some traffic will be dropped somewhere along the way. TCP is designed to handle this by detecting and retransmitting lost segments, and UDP doesn't guarantee delivery, so application using it are expecting to lose some traffic.

Comment: What type of traffic, specifically, do you want this for? I don't know of anything which can't tolerate any loss since that is baked into networking.

Comment: This is going to be mostly TCP traffic. This is meant to limit our traffic going to a MPLS interface, Which we are overcharged if bursting over a certain limit

Comment: The best way to handle TCP is to use RED which randomly drops packets in the queue when it gets close to being full. This will slow down the TCP flows. Trying to not drop any packets is not something that is workable, and you should use the inherent TCP behavior to level out the traffic flows.

Comment: Thank you Ron for your explanations. This is true that at first I didn't think about the packet being dropped if the queue would be full, as the limit would be quite high anyway, but this is something to seriously consider.
I will investigate into this a bit further on my own.
Thanks again

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Traffic shaping is not supported on the 5500-X series devices and the 5540 or below. [Reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/82310-qos-voip-vpn.html#anc6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use policy/class-maps to throttle and shape traffic. In the example below I am restricting traffic to 20 Mbps. After creating the policy I apply the map to the inside interface. Ignore the "TCP-STATE-BYPASS" part of the config:

```
class-map 20_Mbps
 match any

policy-map inside_policy
 class TCP-STATE-BYPASS
  set connection advanced-options tcp-state-bypass
 class 20_Mbps
  police input 20980000
  police output 20980000

service-policy inside_policy interface inside
```

Comment: Policing drops traffic, but the questions asks how to do it without dropping traffic.

Comment: Hmm yea, my bad. I guess shaping would be a more appropriate answer, but, like you said, if the queue fills up packets will eventually be dropped.